# Make a toast when user enters write password in android screen lock

Tags: android

Can I toast a message when user enters wrong password in android screen lock.

Thanks,
Pravin

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this doesn't appear to exist.  (You can use a BroadcastListener to catch when the lockscreen comes on/goes away, but not to capture a failed password attempt.)